# Conditional Moving Average

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a dataframe as below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-06-17','2020-06-18','2020-06-19','2020-06-20','2020-06-21','2020-06-22','2020-06-23','2020-06-24','2020-06-25','2020-06-26','2020-06-27','2020-06-17','2020-06-18','2020-06-19','2020-06-20','2020-06-21','2020-06-22','2020-06-23','2020-06-24','2020-06-25','2020-06-26','2020-06-27'],
                     'Store': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
                     'value':[1,2,0,5,0,2,0,8,1,0,1,4,0,0,2,0,3,6,0,9,2,0],
                      'qty':[1,0,1,4,2,4,6,0,3,0,5,8,0,0,1,0,1,9,3,0,4,1]})
```

[image: data]

I want to calculate the average of "value" column for each store with a window of length 10, but ignoring the 0 qtys. It means that in the window of length 10, the records which have positive qty should be considered in calculating the average of value.
The desired data would be as follow:

[image]

I wrote a solution as bellow, however since my original dataframe has 21 million records and I have almost 2 million stores and I want to calculate this moving average for next 15 days, my solution runs for years and it is totally impractical.

```
for s in range(3):
    adding_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = s)
    start_date = adding_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 10)
    adding_date = adding_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    sub_data = data[(data.Date < adding_date) & (data.Date >= start_date)]
    for index, group in sub_data.groupby(['Store']):
        if group.qty.sum() != 0:
            ma = group[group.qty != 0]['value'].mean()
            row = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[adding_date], 'Store': index[0], 'value': [ma], 'qty': 1})
            data = pd.concat((data,row), ignore_index = True)
        else:
            ma = 0
            row = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[adding_date], 'Store': index[0], 'value': [ma],'qty': 1})
            data = pd.concat((data,row), ignore_index = True)
```

So any help to improve my code would be awesome.

Comment: You have a nested for loop giving you O(n)^2. Start by breaking that into two spearate things.

Comment: @hrokr So how can I avoid for loops? or better say, is there a bulit in function which could handle conditional moving average?

Comment: `df['flg'] = np.where(df['qty'] == 0, 0, 1)` Is it against your intent to add this conditional column and aggregate the moving average for condition = 1 only on a 10-day time series?

Answer (score 1):

```
w_size = 10
```

---

```
sub_df = df.query(f'qty != {0}')

sub_df.ewm(com = w_size).mean() # weighted average 

sub_df.rolling(window=w_size).mean() # average (over window size)
```

---

For just **excluding** some values ​​from calculations, if `value = 0`, then **exclude** row with zeros.

```
df[df['qty'] == value] = 0

df.ewm(com = w_size).mean() # weighted average 

df.rolling(window=w_size).mean() # average (over window size)
```

By setting entirely row, which has zeros `qty` , moving average, just sum zeros for those rows, which same as do nothing (**condtion**), but divided by the window size anyway, if you want exact mean (`divide by the number of non zero`) use the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. btw I guess I should use 2 for loops again and based on hrokr answer this would lead into time complexity... Is it right?

Comment: Yeah sure, `O(m * n)` time complexity

Comment: actually I would like to reduce the calculation time, so it would grateful if I could find a solution to aviod using loops. Thanks anyway...

Comment: The solution above no loops needed, at all

Comment: why you think, you need loops ?, could you please, clarify ?

Comment: the moving average should be calculated for each store and I need to calculate moving average for next 15 days from today.

Comment: Yeah, my comment was somehow ambiguous, I said yeah for `2 for loops` time complexity, but the solution use built-in function, which optimized by `cython` (`C for loop`), there's no need to worry about time.